# Meter React production mode

Tags: cordova, reactjs, meteor

I have a meteor react app and no matter what I do, react still shows up in a dev mode. What should I do to make react production mode? You can see my app at www.Mask.Chat

Comment: Use the minified version of react. How are you importing it into your project?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. I used meteor npm install react react-dom